# when to call StateHasChanged() in Blazor component

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I am trying to figure out when I need to call  StateHasChanged(). I know when changing the value via Javascript, and blazor component may need to be forced to render the page.  In the following code, I have a method called HandleClick to handle the button click and I intentionally commentted out StateHasChanged() . The HandleClick method itself calls Javascript to set the value of element in **Part 2**. Since Blazor component is not aware of the change of the value for fromJs, so the value in **Part 1** is not updated after the click. But the question is why the value in **Part 1** gets changed when I click the button again.

```
@page "/ExampleY"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div class="p-2">
    <p class="alert-info p-3">
       Part 1.  Get value via JS call: <strong>@(fromJs ?? "Empty")</strong>
    </p>

    <p class="alert-success p-3">
        Part 2. Set value via JS call: <strong @ref="element"></strong>
    </p>

    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="HandleClick">Click to Call JS</button>
</div>

@code {
    private string fromJs;
    private ElementReference element;

    public async void HandleClick()
    {
        fromJs = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("setText", element, "Hello from JS call!");
        // StateHasChanged();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with JavaScript Interop.

When you make this change:

```
//public async void HandleClick()
  public async Task HandleClick()
```

then both parts will update at the same time.

Almost always avoid `async void`. It is a last resort for old-style eventhandlers like Timer.Elapsed. Blazor events can return either `void` or `[async] Task`.

> the question is why the value in Part 1 gets changed when I click the button again.

A ButtonClick will always cause a re-render. But because of the `async void` this can happen *before* `fromJs`  is assigned. The await in `await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync(...)` allows that.  On the next click you will see the previous value of fromJs appear in Part 1.
Use `"Hello from JS call! "+DateTime.Now` to see this versioning happen.

Answer (score 2):

The Blazor "internal" event handler code looks like this:

```
var task = InvokeAsync(EventMethod);
StateHasChanged();
if (!task.IsCompleted)
{
    await task;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

If you pass task a void as in:

```
public async void HandleClick()
```

there's nothing to wait on.  `task` is completed and the final render event never takes place.  That's why any `async` handler (i.e. a method with an await), as the one above, must return a Task.

So to answer your questions.  The value in Part 1 is updated, but after the re-render of the component - no Task to wait on.  When you click the button again you show the "last" value, i.e. the one from the last button click, not the current click.  If you set the text to the click time you would see this.

##### Late Addition

You can see the `IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync` code here - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2de2276c384ff14d77985835a46d7573352fb664/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs#L322

Comment: Yes, as you show here there always is  1 call to StateHasChanged(). And a 2nd one for async handlers.  I was looking for this piece.

Comment: @HenkHolterman.  You see the same basic pattern repeated in a lot of the Blazor code base - as in how `ComponentBase` runs `OnInitializedAsync` and `OnParametersSetAsync`.