# Should i call StateHasChanged everytime a value is changed

Tags: blazor-server-side

look at this blazor server page:

```
@page "/"

<div>@Field1</div>
<div>@Field2</div>

<button @onclick="OnBtnClick">Btn</button>

@code
{
    public String Field1 { get; set; }
    public String Field2 { get; set; }

    private async Task OnBtnClick()
    {
        Field1 = "test1";

        // Value is displayed but i have not called StateHasChanged() there...


        await Task.Delay(1000);

        Field2 = "test2";
    }
}
```

There is something i do not understand:

As you can see, i do not call StateHasChanged.

When i click on the button, i can see "test1" value displayed on the page, then wait 1 second and then i can see "test2".

I know StateHasChanged is automatically called after the event. But is it called automatically before the Task.Delay too ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a related question: [when to call StateHasChanged() in Blazor component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69135844/when-to-call-statehaschanged-in-blazor-component)

It appears to indicate that `StateHasChanged` is automatically called in your example after the `Task.Delay` function is await-ed.

The other article says the Blazor "internal" event handler code looks like this:

```
var task = InvokeAsync(EventMethod);
StateHasChanged();
if (!task.IsCompleted)
{
    await task;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: I do not understand : this mean StateHasChanged() should be automatically called in my case...

Comment: Yes that's right.  Blazor will call StateHasChanged() 1st when your await Task.Delay(1000) line is called,  then it will call StateHasChanged() again after OnBtnClick() is complete.    It's the await Task.Delay(1000) that triggers the additional StateHasChanged() call that makes "test1" show up.     If you were using some other "await" besides Task.Delay then it would depend if that code actually runs synchronously or not, so StateHasChanged() may or may not be called again, but in your example it is.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it has provided you the information you requested, thank you.

Comment: Additional information about when to call StateHasChanged()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-6.0#an-asynchronous-handler-involves-multiple-asynchronous-phases